# Trying to split a string that's a key from a dict in python, getting unexplained error. Why?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

For some reason I'm getting an error on these lines of code in Python:

```
for identity in identities.iterkeys():
    if "twitter" in identity: 
        OUT.write(identity.rsplit('/', 0))
```

And this is the error that I'm getting:

```
OUT.write(identity.rsplit('/', 0))
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list
```

I'm utterly confused why the `if "twitter"` line would work but the rsplit would not and I've been beating my head against this all night. (The string is a URL, if that makes any difference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsplit` returns a list. You need to retrieve the string again.

```
OUT.write(identity.rsplit('/', 0)[0])
```

BTW, `identity.rsplit('/', 0')[0]` just returns your `identity` string unchanged. May be you are looking for `identity.rsplit('/', 1)[1]`.

Comment: ... wow, I feel dumb now. I often find the Python documentation to be really hard to read. This line from the [split documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) - "(thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements)" - seemed to indicate that returning 1 result was the default. Which I guess it is. But it's not what I expected. Thanks.